# Ruby byebug never stops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, byebug

Ruby byebug never seems to stop in any of my code.  It installed properly without errors.  I did a bundle update byebug as well as gem pristine byebug.  I start the rails server with this command rails s -e development

Here's the gem file

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

#ruby  '2.0.0'

gem 'multi_json', '1.7.8' 
gem 'rails' #, '4.0.5'
#gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: "rails/activerecord-session_store", branch: 'master'
gem "activerecord-session_store", "~> 0.1.0"
gem 'devise', '3.1.1'
gem 'rolify', '~> 3.4'
gem 'cancan', '~> 1.6.10'
#gem "resque", "~> 2.0.0.pre.1", github: "resque/resque"
gem 'resque', '~> 1.25.1', :require=>"resque/server"
gem 'resque-retry', '~> 1.0.0.a'
gem 'resque-scheduler', '~> 2.5.3', :require => "resque_scheduler/server"
gem 'resque-pool', '~> 0.3.0'
gem 'resque_mailer', '~> 2.2.6'
gem 'god', '~> 0.13.4'

gem 'gravtastic', '~> 3.2.3', :require => "gravtastic"

gem 'aws-ses', '~> 0.6.0', :require => 'aws/ses'


# stripe/payments
gem 'stripe', '~> 1.10.1'
gem 'stripe_event', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'stripe-rails', '~> 0.2.6'
gem 'koudoku', '~> 0.0.11'

# ultra hook for wen hook testing
gem 'ultrahook', '~> 0.1.3'

# bill data
gem 'sunlight', '~> 1.1.0'
gem 'congress', '~> 0.2.3'
gem 'openstates', '~> 0.0.1'



#admin stuff
# gem 'rails_admin', '~> 0.6.1'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.5'
gem "statsd-ruby", :require => "statsd"
gem 'paperclip', '= 3.5.4'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.5.7'
gem 'roadie', '~> 2.4.3'
gem 'exception_notification', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'exception_handler', '~> 0.3.45'
gem 'spawnling', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'acts_as_list', '~> 0.4.0'

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
gem "jquery-ui-rails", '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-timepicker-rails', '~> 1.3.7'
gem 'time_splitter', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.17.1'
gem 'gibbon', "~> 1.0.4"
gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 4.0.1"

gem 'carmen', "~> 1.0.1"
gem 'nested_form', "~> 0.3.2"
gem 'simple_form', "~> 3.0.2"

gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'tinymce-rails', "~> 4.0.19"
gem 'fileuploader-rails', '= 3.5'

gem 'email_validator', "~> 1.4.0"

gem "impressionist", "~> 1.5.1"

gem 'rack-timeout', '~> 0.0.4'

gem 'protected_attributes', '~> 1.0.8'

# Gem to embed youtube/vimeo videos
gem 'conred', '~> 0.5.0'
# Gem to implement copy to clipboard functionality via flash
gem 'zeroclipboard-rails', '~> 0.1.0'

gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.1.9'

gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer', '~> 0.2.8'

gem 'newrelic_rpm', '~> 3.9.6.257'

# to put environment variable configurations
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.1.1'

gem 'byebug'
gem 'pry-byebug'

# better way of displaying errors on dev
gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'binding_of_caller', '~> 0.7.2'

#gem 'debugger', '~> 1.6.8'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.1'
  gem 'timecop', '~> 0.7.1'
  gem 'spork', '~> 1.0rc'
  gem 'guard', "~> 2.6.0"
  gem 'guard-rspec', "~> 4.2.8"
  gem 'rb-fsevent', "~> 0.9.3"
  gem "jasmine-rails", "~> 0.5.1"

end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
  gem "compass-rails", "~> 1.1.2"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
end
```

Comment: where you have wrote `byebug` in your code?

Comment: I put in in multiple places.  Here's the landing page.

def index
    byebug
    render layout: 'subscribe_beta'
  end

Comment: have you see your command prompt to check is that stop executing or not?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't stop. The entire web page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had downgrade to a lower version of byebug and it works.  Not sure what incompatibilities there may have been with the latest version.  Using 3.5.1 worked for me.

```
gem 'byebug', '~> 3.5.1'
```